# In sqlalchemy how to access anonymous field in subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, polymorphism, subquery, anonymous

First, I used Sqlalchemy's polymorphic architecture.
`ChildA` and `ChildB` extends `Child`.

`ChildA` has `name` column.

`ChildB` has `age` column.

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship(Parent, backref='children')

class ChildA(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'child_a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

class ChildB(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'child_b'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    age = Column(Integer)


parent = DBSession.query(Parent).first()
subquery = parent.children.join(ChildA).subquery()
```

So I want to access `ChildA.name` column from `subquery`.
Something like `subquery.c.ChildA.name == 'Tom'`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly what you are trying to do, you don't really need a subquery, it could be simply something like

```
In [13]:

f = session.query(Parent, ChildA).join(ChildA).first()
print(f.ChildA.name)

Pedro
```

For the use of subqueries, I would recommend you take a look to `sqlalchemy` [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries).

On the other hand, I wasn't able to use the classes as you've defined them, I had to add a `ForeignKey` like this

```
class ChildA(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'child_a'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

class ChildB(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'child_b'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'), primary_key=True)
    age = Column(Integer)
```

I have no doubt that it works for you, this probably depends on the setup.

And finally, I would like to recommend you to use a column for the type of child. With this, it will be easier to recognize the children you are using. Something like this,

```
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship(Parent, backref='children')
    type = Column(String(20))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'child',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }

class ChildA(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'child_a'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'child_a',
    }

class ChildB(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'child_b'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'), primary_key=True)
    age = Column(Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'child_b',
    }
```

Please take a look to `sqlalchemy` [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/inheritance.html) for details.

Hope it helps.